# как правильно увеличить размер массива?

Tags: c, память, malloc, realloc

Я давно откладывал эту тему, но думаю переходить на компиляцию С++, каждый раз когда мне нужен вектор, будет не самым лучшим решением.
я попробовал использовать такой вариант увеличения.

```
char* screen;
int main() {
screen = malloc(120 * 30);
...

if (x == strlen(screen)) {
    char* _new = realloc(screen, strlen(screen) * 2);
    screen = _new;
}
```

Я знаю что если на адрес памяти нет ссылок, то ОС сама его очистит. В данном случае я создаю новый указатель и присваиваю старому массиву эту ссылку. Мне нужно чистить _new? Или это не нужно? Если я понял что-то не так, или я просто не внимательный, прошу простить и объяснить.

Comment: Очень странно. Я, конечно, не вижу весь код... Но если у вас там записана короткая строка? Кой смысл ориентироваться на длину хранящейся строки, а не на размер буфера? По сути: ОС его очистит только по окончании работы программы (в С/С++ нет сборки мусора). При выделении новой памяти большего размера старая информация будет перенесена в новый блок. Так что с этой точки зрения все нормально. Но вот проверить, что не вернулся `NULL`, надо, а то устроите себе утечку и вообще веселую жизнь...

Comment: Простите, я забыл упомянуть. Весь массив уже инициализирован пробелами. И спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Все равно плохо. Нет никакой гарантии, что ЗА массивом обязательно будет нулевой символ. Вобщем, не используйте `strlen` — она не для того предназначена! храните размер выделенной памяти в отдельной переменной.

Comment: любые переменные с указателями не удаляют память, куда они направлены после выхода из области жизни. Выделение памяти и освобождение уже на совести программиста.

Comment: А вы точно понимаете, что делает `strlen`? Она никак не сможет определить размер того, что строкой не является. Попробуйте сделать структуру, в которой будет храниться указатель, размер доступного блока памяти (capacity в векторе) и размер задействованного куска памяти.

Comment: если вы переходите на c++ почему бы вам не использовать `std::vector`

Comment: А вообще, такие задачи хорошо решаются с помощью ООП. Создаёте класс `CScreen`, а в нём поля, скажем,  `m_width, m_height, m_size, m_pBuffer`, и набор методов, скажем `Resize(), Print()`, и т.п. Но у вас в тегах C, так что с классами не получится. Но можно класс заменить на структуру, а методы - на функции, принимающие указатель на структуру явно. Получится тот же принцип, что и в ООП, только на Си.

Comment: *"Я знаю что если на адрес памяти нет ссылок, то ОС сама его очистит."* - это вы спутали С с языками со сборщиком мусора, типа Java, go или C#. В С память освобождается всегда вручную. В данном случае происходит утечка памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `realloc` может привести к одному из двух результатов:

- Функция успешно увеличила массив — тогда она вернёт указатель на новый. Старый массив **уже удалён**, а все данные скопированы в новый. Обратите внимание, что функция может вернуть тот же самый указатель что вы в неё передали — это нормально, это значит что новый массив был создан на месте старого.
- Недостаточно памяти — функция вернёт NULL. Старый массив **не удалён**, если он вам не нужен — его нужно удалить с помощью `free`.

К вашему коду два замечания:

- Не используйте `strlen`. Заведите отдельную переменную, которая будет хранить ёмкость массива.
- Результат `realloc` нужно проверять на NULL.

> Я знаю что если на адрес памяти нет ссылок, то ОС сама его очистит.

Это неправда! ОС очищает память только когда ваша программа завершилась. Если вы хотите вывести сообщение об ошибке и завершить программу — то память освобождать не обязательно. Если же вы хотите продолжить работу — указатели на ненужную память надо передавать в функцию `free`. Однако помните — некоторые функции (такие как `realloc`) сами освобождают память — нужно смотреть в справочнике по конкретной функции. Также, ни в коем случае нельзя передавать уже освобождённую память в `free` во второй раз!

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Тут очень много полезной информации.